# Yii2 and href: How to specifies the link's destination using?

Tags: php, hyperlink, path, yii2, href

I use Yii2 framework and I want to have a link in a php file called **index.php** to a pdf file called **abc.pdf** but the path that I wrote is not working:

I have these files:

- my-project/backend/views/my-form/index.php
- my-project/backend/views/my-form/abc.pdf

This is code of the element that is not working of index.php:

```
<a href="abc.pdf">Link to abc</a>
```

Which is the path that should work? I tried relative and absolut paths but I think I am writing it wrong.

Comment: All public files (in this case, pdf) must be in web folder. So, put abc.pdf in my-project/backend/web folder, and link to it using \Yii::getAlias('@web/abc.pdf') inside backend environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it doing the folowing.

I placed the **abc.pdf** file in the **/backend/web** folder.

Then I referenced it at index.php using:

```
<a href="abc.pdf">
```

Answer (score 0):

try using  `html helpers`  for build the correct path

```
    use  yii\helpers\Html;

    <?= Html::a('Link to abc', ['my-form/abc.pdf']) ?>
```

see here for more  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#hyperlinks

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to pass it in href attribute; use

```
<a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/site/registeruser']) ?>" class="btn btn-success">Profile</a>
```